# Jenkins : configuration-as-code-plugin upgrade issue

Tags: jenkins-plugins

My jenkins is version: `Jenkins 2.289.3` (we install by deploy jenkin.war file in tomcat). Configuration-as-code-plugin: configuration-as-code 1.43 upgrade to -> 1.51.

After upgrade i got issue below:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/run/secrets/secrets.properties" "read")
    at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:897)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:322)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:661)
    at java.base/java.io.File.exists(File.java:826)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.secrets.PropertiesSecretSource.init(PropertiesSecretSource.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:757)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:638)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configure(ConfigurationAsCode.java:307)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.init(ConfigurationAsCode.java:299)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1129)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1162)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:960)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:295)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:312)
```

I already tried to delete current plugin and reinstall. Still same issue.

I also tried installing lower version but same for 1.46, 1.47, 1.48, 1.49, 1.50